# Work with xml in c#

Tags: c#, xml, file, xml-serialization

I want to do something like this in my program with c# code:
if a xml file does not exists create it and insert an object of a class in it, else if it has created already but the creation time is just today add my object at the end of it, else clear current xml file and insert the object in it.

how can i do that?

Note:i almost did it by "xmlSerializer", but i couldnt add data at the end of my xml file.

Comment: also show what you have done till now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the LINQ to XML class XElement. It is quite handy. You may still need to use the XmlSerializer in order to turn your object to XML. When using the XMLSerializer make sure you use a static one as the constructor for XmlSerializer is very heavy.

Start off by adding A reference to System.Xml.Linq.
You can use XElement.Load to read the existing xml from a file.
You can use .Parse to read the xml string from your serialized object.
You can use the add method to add your xml to the endof the xml you read.
And .Save to write it out to a file.
Here is the msdn referenece for XElement http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.aspx

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Nothing));
ser.Serialize(sw, new Nothing(){AStringInNothing = "asd"});
sw.ToString();
var whatYouWant = XElement.Parse(sw.ToString());
```

Comment: thanks,but i did not work with linq yet,please help me to start.

Comment: as mentioned by kmcc049 you don't have to use LINQ queries - it is enough to start using XElement.Load and XElement.Parse...

Comment: @kmcc049,thanks.i used XElement class and do my work but i have wanted something like XmlSerializer which Serialize a class with all of its attributes in the xml file.is there any way?can i merge these two classes(XElement and XmlSerializer) to achieve my aim?

Comment: sure get the output of the XmlSerializer a a string and use XElement.Parse() to load that into an XElement.

Comment: @kmcc049,thanks but the output of XmlSerializer.Serialize is not string, it is void!